# Adding rows in rails from CSV

Tags: ruby

I am looking to import a csv file with header to rails app. 
I have the following in my model:

```
def self.import(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    puts(*attribute_names)
    puts(row.to_hash)
    @distrib = Distrib.create! row.to_hash
  end
end
```

My controller:

```
def import
  Distrib.import(params[:file])
  redirect_to distribs_path, notice: "Contact imported."
end
```

My view:

```
<%= form_tag({action: :import}, multipart: true)  do %>
    <%= file_field_tag :file %>
    <%= submit_tag "Import" %>
<% end %>
```

I managed to create the right number of records, but they are all empty.

`puts(row.to_hash)` returns the following:

```
{"email;first_name;last_name;telephone;company;address;city;country;memo"=>"Etienny@yahoo.fr;Etienne;Ton;22142536475;HKM;456 Fifth Avenue;New York;US;Met at Uni"}
```

How do I process these rows properly for insertion into a PostgreSQL database?

Comment: You should **not** amend questions according to the response. I reverted the change back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the problems with your code might be that CSV stands for *comma-separated values" file, but you have a semicolon separator. Try this:

```
CSV.foreach(file.path, {headers: true, col_sep: ";"}) do |row|
   puts(*attribute_names)
   puts(row.to_hash)
   ...
end
```

This should have `puts(row.to_hash)` to have the right output.

Comment: Hey, i just amended my question using your response. But there is still no input being processed. What do you think ?

Comment: @Etienne I'm not familiar with the `Distrib` object that much, but maybe `.create!` is the wrong method to use?

Comment: I was thinking that too. How do I extract the component or row.to_hash, one by one, for example the email row[:email] returns nil.

Comment: @Etienne `row[:email]` is nil because your fields are strings. Are you following any tutorial or guide to do this?

Comment: I was following : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W8pohTautj8, it seems very easy the way he does it, but god i have been on this for 3h